# update clipPath alongside a dynamic yaxis in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/ed1b5bfc5b7356ae7313cf78f0e75518) **(SOLVED)** chart and I can't figure out how to update clipPath.
I've commented out

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; }));
```

in the change function because it didn't update the clipPath alongside the yAxis, I've tried to assign a class to the clipPath and update the y and height attribute in the change function but nothing seem to work.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or why it's not possible to update clipPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the new domain, but you also need to update those things based on the domain (both clip-paths and the area's y0):

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; })); // fix clipPath

svg.select('#clip-below>rect')
  .attr("y", y(1))
  .attr("height", height - y(1));   
svg.select('#clip-above>rect')
  .attr("height", y(1));
 area.y0(y(1));
```

Here's an updated [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/abe8767c8d84fdb52e0e1387db69e9d7).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what exactly does the '>rect' section do? I've never seen it before.

Comment: `#clip-below>rect` means find me the `rect` element that has a parent with id of "clip-below".